# Redirecting from Login Viewto ChangePassword View in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a very simple ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile application, that require a Login page and after successful Login the user is redirected to a landing page ( list of orders).
If the Login process return a value that the user password expired, then the user will be redirected to a Change Password page.

I am trying to do this redirection to the Change Password page, but for some reason, I am always redirected back to the Login page.
I am using this code in the controller ( taken mostly from the MVC4 Web Application sample in VS2012) -

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
...
if (retValue.Equals("ChangePassword"))
    RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that the ChangePassword View is in the same AccountContoller of the Login view.
there is LoginModel and ChangePasswordModel as well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to **`return`** the redirect. Try this:

```
if (retValue.Equals("ChangePassword"))
    return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Account");
```